# Use of that and to the point that

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, relative-clauses, that

Am I using the *that*-clause in this sentence properly?

> "Watching just the first episode of the anime will surely get you hooked **that** you would want to marathon the whole series in a day."

Or should I add *to the point* as in "will surely get you hooked *to the point that* you would want to marathon the whole series in a day"?

Comment: You could also say "so hooked that". "that" alone does not work, but "to the point that" does. Also I'd use "will" instead of "would".

Comment: And "binge-watch" instead of "marathon".

Comment: I've never heard *marathon* used as a verb (in BrE); hence "to marathon" is strange.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add 'so' to your example sentence for it to make sense: -

> "Watching just the first episode of the anime will surely get you
>   **so** hooked that you would want to marathon the whole series in a day."

Your are using 'that' as a conjunction here, [see this example](http://partofspeech.org/what-part-of-speech-is-that/) (part 2.b): -

> She was so exhausted that she couldn’t think straight.

The [verb marathon](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/marathon#Verb) does work, although it is very rarely used, so some readers will find it a little unusual (which isn't necessarily bad in itself, but just something to be aware of).

Regarding the second part of your question "should I add to the point", I would recommend against that structure, it reads rather cumbersome compared to what you originally had which is more succinct, you just need to add 'so' as discussed above, before hooked, for it to make sense.